# Next best choice when Context is not applicable

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I need two React components to exchange data, but I cannot use React Context. That is something I have no control on, I am bringing two separate third party "widgets" to different areas of a same Web page.

What options do I have? For now, what I have done is create a standalone object that I am importing in both components. Are there any concerns with this, and is there a better way?

Shared object: PP_Properties.js

```
function PP_PropertiesFactory()  {
    let properties = {Property1: null, Property2: null, Property3: null};

    const updateProperties = ({targetProperty, newValue}) => properties[targetProperty] = newValue;

    return {...properties, updateProperties};
}

export const PP_Properties = PP_PropertiesFactory();
```

Widget 1 component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {PP_Properties} from './PP_Properties';

export const Widget1Component = (props) => {
  // Use PP_Properties in this element
  // Update PP_Properties using the updateProperties() method
};
```

Widget 2 component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';

import {PP_Properties} from './PP_Properties';

export class Widget2ComponentBuilder {
  // Consume PP_Properties in this element
  // Update PP_Properties using updateProperties()
}

export function Widget2Component() {
  return new Widget2ComponentBuilder();
};
```

Comment: Why can't you use the Context API? Can you control the props passed to both widgets and where the widgets live in the app structure? Using *some* global object in react is generally an anti-pattern, but if that is what you need then ensuring any updates to it will need to be managed manually as it would be completely outside the react ecosystem.

Comment: Because of the way the page is structured (not under my control), I cannot position those two components under a same MyContext.Provider component. Thanks for the comment, indeed it feels like an anti-pattern.

Comment: I guess it is unclear to me (*sans more context*) how you have access to the source to do the work but can't place a context provider, or this additional logic, in a common ancestor to either widget component.

Comment: I don't have access to the source, the "widget" provides the general structure and placeholders where I can insert custom components. Sorry I can't share more.

Comment: No worries, just trying to understand your use-case and restrictions better. So you are basically also creating a 3rd-party module that "injects" react components into placeholders? Is this a slightly more accurate description? Is it possible to use a react portal to create a common ancestor and have both widgets wrapped in a HOC that can interact with central logic in the portal component and feed the properties into the widgets?

Comment: Great point. I kind of discarded this option because the placeholder constraints are very strict, but I'll take a closer look. I was just hoping for a pattern that could apply when context does not. I am actually using a portal, but for a different purpose.

Comment: @Christophe For a simple library that implements global state like capabilities, try zustand - https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading, it seems that what I am asking for is a library that does global state management, such as Redux.

A full blown library is probably an overkill for my simple needs, so I am looking at more lightweight options. The names I've heard so far are mobx, ReactN, React Entities and React Capsule.

An even simpler approach is to keep my initial idea of an object imported and manipulated by both components. As @drew-reese said, it looked like an anti-pattern at first but that's actually how those state management libraries work.

Here is an example:

https://dev.to/muhammadawaisshaikh/the-simplest-way-to-share-data-between-two-unrelated-components-in-react-1md0